# Building Qt once added to subversion?

Tags: windows, svn, qt, qt4

I need to make some changes to Qt 4.7.1, so I need to add it to my subversion server to track my changes. However, once it's added, the configure script fails. I'm guessing it's choking on the .svn files.

I'm using Windows. Is there any way to add Qt to subversion, delete all the .svn folders, configure and build it, recreate the .svn folders, and then submit my changes?

Or is there any other work around? The error I get is 'Couldn't update default mkspec'

Comment: Are you sure it's because of the .svn files? Perhaps you have messed something up, like ignoring some files or setting svn:eol-style on wrong files. Did you try comparing the original folder with the one checked out? Is the presence of the .svn files the only difference?

Comment: I'm using different subversioned sources of Qt SDK's and there is no any trouble with configuring. May be you are missing something else (file/folder permissions ?).

Comment: I install Qt 4.7.1 and type configure, it works. I delete the folder. I reinstall, svn add, svn commit. It fails. Not sure what else it could be.

Comment: I don't get it. Adding and committing only works with working directories, so you should have done svn import and svn checkout first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is if .svn folders exist in /mkspecs/default and /mkspecs-win32-msvc2008 then configure fails to run with the error 'Couldn't update default mkspec'

If I move the .svn folders, configure, then replace them, I can then build.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would have done:

1. Install Qt in some folder.
2. Make sure that auto-props and global-ignores are set up properly.
3. Rename the whole folder.
4. Create an empty repository.
5. Create an empty folder having the same name as the original one.
6. Import the empty folder into the repository.
7. Remove the folder.
8. Check out the folder.
9. Copy the contents of the backup to the working copy.
10. Carefully add everything you want to be source controlled, probably using the `-N` or `--depth` options.
11. Put everything else into appropriate svn:ignore properties.
12. Commit.
13. Compare the working copy and the backup.
14. If there are any differences, wipe both the working directory and the repository, then repeat from the step 2, correcting the mistakes.

It may seem a bit of overkill, but importing such a large project into an SVN repository isn't a trivial task.